# oracle assigning integer value bigger than 3 digits to a bind variable gets ORA-06502 error

Tags: oracle, plsql, zend-framework

I need to get the generated `id` out from an oracle `INSERT` statement with `RETURING INTO` and subsequently access that value through zend framework `paramContainer` object.

If the `id` number is bigger than 3 digits I get this error:

**ORA-06502: PL/SQL: errore : buffer della stringa di caratteri troppo piccolo di numero o valore**

This is the `zend-framework` part:

```
$paramContainer = new ParameterContainer();
$paramContainer->offsetSet('cod_fis', $this->cf_dipendente, $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('matricola', $this->matr_dipendente, $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('dataPresentazione', $validatedData['dataPresentazione'], $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('obiettivo', $validatedData["obiettivo"], $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('retval', '0', $paramContainer::TYPE_STRING);
$paramContainer->offsetSetReference('id_progetto', 'retval');
```

This is the code returning the error:

```
DECLARE
  id_progetto NUMBER;
  retval      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_PROGETTO (COD_FIS, MATRICOLA, STATO, STATO_INTERNO, DATA_PRESENTAZIONE, DATA_ULTIMA_MODIFICA)
  VALUES (:cod_fis, :matricola, 'A', 'C', TO_DATE(:dataPresentazione, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
          SYSDATE) RETURNING id INTO :id_progetto; /* id is 4 digits long */

  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_OBIETTIVO (ID_PROGETTO, OBIETTIVO)
  VALUES (:id_progetto, :obiettivo);

  :retval := :id_progetto;


END;
```

While this code works:

```
DECLARE
  id_progetto NUMBER;
  retval      NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_PROGETTO (COD_FIS, MATRICOLA, STATO, STATO_INTERNO, DATA_PRESENTAZIONE, DATA_ULTIMA_MODIFICA)
  VALUES (:cod_fis, :matricola, 'A', 'C', TO_DATE(:dataPresentazione, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
          SYSDATE) RETURNING SUBSTR(id,1,3) INTO :id_progetto; /* here I'm truncating the number to 3 digits */

  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_OBIETTIVO (ID_PROGETTO, OBIETTIVO)
  VALUES (:id_progetto, :obiettivo);

  :retval := :id_progetto;
END;
```

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the Zend code that is reading the bind variable because the error is not going to be in the PL/SQL but in the Zend/PHP code where you declare the bind variables.

Comment: Also, you are not using the local `id_progetto` or `retval` PL/SQL variables in the `DECLARE` section; instead, you always use the `:id_progetto` and `:retval` bind variable declared globally. You can either remove the `:` from in front of those variables to use the local PL/SQL variable or remove the variables from the `DECLARE` section (or even the entire `DECLARE` section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing local PL/SQL variables defined in the `DECLARE` clause and globally defined bind variables prefixed with `:`. They are not the same variable even though they may have the same identifier.

What you probably want is:

```sql
DECLARE
  id_progetto NUMBER;  -- local variable
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_PROGETTO (
    COD_FIS,
    MATRICOLA,
    STATO,
    STATO_INTERNO,
    DATA_PRESENTAZIONE,
    DATA_ULTIMA_MODIFICA
  ) VALUES (
    :cod_fis, :matricola,
    'A',
    'C',
    TO_DATE(:dataPresentazione, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    SYSDATE
  ) RETURNING id INTO id_progetto; -- into the local variable

  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_OBIETTIVO (
    ID_PROGETTO, OBIETTIVO
  ) VALUES (
    id_progetto, :obiettivo -- read the local variable
  );

  :retval := id_progetto; -- out into the global bind variable
END;
```

Possibly [using](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/4088):

```php
$paramContainer = new ParameterContainer();
$paramContainer->offsetSet('cod_fis', $this->cf_dipendente, $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('matricola', $this->matr_dipendente, $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('dataPresentazione', $validatedData['dataPresentazione'], $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('obiettivo', $validatedData["obiettivo"], $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('retval', '0', $paramContainer::TYPE_STRING);
$paramContainer->offsetSetReference('retval', 'retval');
```

or, do not use any local variables:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_PROGETTO (
    COD_FIS,
    MATRICOLA,
    STATO,
    STATO_INTERNO,
    DATA_PRESENTAZIONE,
    DATA_ULTIMA_MODIFICA
  ) VALUES (
    :cod_fis, :matricola,
    'A',
    'C',
    TO_DATE(:dataPresentazione, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    SYSDATE
  ) RETURNING id INTO :id_progetto; /* id is 4 digits long */

  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_OBIETTIVO (
    ID_PROGETTO, OBIETTIVO
  ) VALUES (
    :id_progetto, :obiettivo
  );
END;
```

then:

```php
$paramContainer = new ParameterContainer();
$paramContainer->offsetSet('cod_fis', $this->cf_dipendente, $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('matricola', $this->matr_dipendente, $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('dataPresentazione', $validatedData['dataPresentazione'], $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('obiettivo', $validatedData["obiettivo"], $paramContainer::TYPE_AUTO);
$paramContainer->offsetSet('id_progetto', '0', $paramContainer::TYPE_STRING);
$paramContainer->offsetSetReference('id_progetto', 'id_progetto');
```

You also should not pass dates as strings and should just use a `DATE` data type (in Oracle, a `DATE` always has a time component; which may mean that the equivalent in Zend is a timestamp data type rather than a date).

If you do pass it as an Oracle `DATE` then your code becomes:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_PROGETTO (
    COD_FIS,
    MATRICOLA,
    STATO,
    STATO_INTERNO,
    DATA_PRESENTAZIONE,
    DATA_ULTIMA_MODIFICA
  ) VALUES (
    :cod_fis, :matricola,
    'A',
    'C',
    :dataPresentazione,
    SYSDATE
  ) RETURNING id INTO :id_progetto; /* id is 4 digits long */

  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_OBIETTIVO (
    ID_PROGETTO, OBIETTIVO
  ) VALUES (
    :id_progetto, :obiettivo
  );
END;
```

and you would not want to use `::TYPE_AUTO` in the Zend code but specify the actual type of the bind variable (if Zend supports `::TYPE_DATE` or `::TYPE_TIMESTAMP`, which is not obvious that it does).

---

For your Zend code, you want to make sure that whichever of `id_progetto` and/or `retval` you are using is declared as an `OUT` or `IN/OUT` parameter bind variable and not an `IN` parameter.

From [this bug](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/4088), it appears you need to use both `offsetSet` and `offsetSetReference` on the same bind parameter (but the Zend/Lamina documentation appears to be almost useless on giving descriptions of what these methods are supposed to do and does not give practical examples that obviously identify `OUT` or `IN/OUT` bind variables).

Comment: Ok thank you. Now I get the local/global variable difference. But how can I get the value to zend? offsetGet doesn't work.

Comment: @alzambo I don't use Zend/Lamina so I cannot tell you how. I spent 10 minutes trying to search for/read the `ParameterContainer` documentation and the official documentation is utterly useless as there are no descriptions of what the methods are intended to be used for and the examples are not helpful for this use case. You can try the solution [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/4088). I've updated the answer with my best guess as to the solution.

Comment: I think I've solved using oci_bind_by_name($statement->getResource(),":id_progetto", $retval, 100, OCI_B_INT  ) as suggested in the link. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

ORA-06502 can be result of you trying to execute a statement that resulted in an arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error.

- You tried to assign a value to a numeric variable, but the value is larger than the variable can handle

  - that's what you reported
- You tried to assign a non-numeric value to a numeric variable and caused a conversion error

  - that what *smells* wrong here

If you managed to make it work using `substr`, is it possible that value returned by the `insert` statement is actually a **string** (e.g. `123A`) which can't fit into a `NUMBER` datatype variable?

Because, there's no problem in storing a 4-digits number into a  non-constrained `NUMBER` datatype variable.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_id_progetto number;
  3  begin
  4    l_id_progetto := 123456789;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Furthermore, this is what you're doing (simplified):

```
DECLARE
  id_progetto NUMBER;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LAVORO_TELE_PROGETTO (...)
  RETURNING id INTO :id_progetto; 
                    ^
                    |
      what is this colon doing here?
```

Shouldn't it be

```
returning id into id_progetto
```

instead? Looks like you're inserting it into ... huh, something out of this PL/SQL procedure (e.g. an Oracle Forms field, Apex page item, whatever which actually *is* capable of holding only 3 *characters*, but - not the locally declared variable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked but I need to get that returned "id_progetto" value out from PL/SQL. I need to pass it to Zend ParameterContainer offsetSetReference() method. If I try to get it with :retval := id_progetto (without colon) I have the same error on the :retval variable. See here https://datadrivendesign.net/read/zf2-query-helpers-and-oracle-bound-in-out-variables for a quick guide.

Comment: I don't know anything about Zend. Did you check whether `:id_progetto` (that's in Zend, right?) accepts values larger than 3 digits (characters)? If not, **enlarge it**.